# Unable to process some fields

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using JSF with Primefaces 4, I have a crud with a tabPanel and I want to process just a few fields when clicking on save button, so I surrounded the fields with a h:panelGroup with an id and add the process attributte to my p:commandButton. There is the code:

As I am using facelets to define templates I will post from the start:

My crudTemplate.xhtml

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/sistema.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:define name="conteudo">

    <ui:insert name="cabecalho">
        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/template/componentes/titulo.xhtml"/>
    </ui:insert>

    <ui:insert name="corpo">
        <p:growl id="growl" autoUpdate="true" sticky="true" globalOnly="true"/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="box border primary">
                    <div class="box-title">
                        <h4>#{tituloCorpo}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <ui:insert name="areaTabs">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="tabbable header-tabs">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

                                    <ui:insert name="tabPesquisa">
                                        <li><a href="#box_tab_pesquisa"
                                            data-toggle="tab" accesskey="p"><i
                                                class="fa fa-search"></i> <span
                                                class="hidden-inline-mobile"><u>P</u>esquisar</span> </a></li>
                                    </ui:insert>

                                    <ui:insert name="tabCadastro">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#box_tab_cadastro" data-toggle="tab"
                                            accesskey="c"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> <span
                                                class="hidden-inline-mobile"><u>C</u>adastrar</span> </a></li>
                                    </ui:insert>

                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div id="box_tab_cadastro" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                                        <h:panelGroup id="panelContentCadastro" layout="block">
                                            <ui:insert name="conteudoTabCadastro">
                                                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/template/cadastro/areaCadastro.xhtml"/>
                                            </ui:insert>    
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="box_tab_pesquisa" class="tab-pane fade">
                                        <h:panelGroup id="panelContentPesquisa" layout="block">
                                            <ui:insert name="conteudoTabPesquisa">
                                                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/template/pesquisa/areaPesquisa.xhtml"/>
                                            </ui:insert>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ui:insert>
                    <ui:insert name="dialogsAdicionais"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ui:insert>
</ui:define>
```

This one is the specific crud:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/crudTemplate.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:max="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/tags">

<ui:param name="tituloCabecalho" value="Cadastro de Clientes Software House" />
<ui:param name="descricaoCabecalho" value="Cadastre, Pesquisa, Altere e Exclua Clientes Software House" />
<ui:param name="tituloCorpo" value="Clientes Software House" />
<ui:param name="controller" value="#{clienteSoftwareHouseController}"/>

<ui:define name="conteudoTabCadastro">
    <h:panelGroup id="panelGroupCadastro" layout="block">
        <h:form prependId="false">
            <p:tabView id="tabViewCadastroEcf">
                <ui:include src="/restrito/cliente_software_house/tabClienteCadastro.xhtml" />
                <ui:include src="/restrito/cliente_software_house/tabContatosCadastro.xhtml" />
                <ui:include src="/restrito/cliente_software_house/tabEnderecosCadastro.xhtml" />
                <ui:include src="/restrito/cliente_software_house/tabEcfCadastro.xhtml" />
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="dialogsAdicionais">
    <ui:include src="/restrito/pessoa/dialogTabelaPessoas.xhtml" /> 
    <ui:include src="/restrito/contador/dialogVinculoContador.xhtml" />
    <ui:include src="/restrito/item_categoria_cliente/dialogVinculoItemCategoriaCliente.xhtml" />
    <ui:include src="/restrito/grupo_cliente/dialogVinculoGrupoCliente.xhtml" />
    <ui:include src="/restrito/ecf/dialogHistoricos.xhtml" />

    <p:confirmDialog id="exclusaoHistoricoEcfId" appendTo="@(body)"
        message="Voce deseja realmente excluir?" header="Confirmação"
        severity="alert" widgetVar="exclusaoHistoricoEcf">
        <h:form prependId="false">
            <div style="margin-left: 60px">
                <p:commandButton value="Sim" process="@this"
                    oncomplete="exclusaoHistoricoEcf.hide()" update="@([id$=formDialogHistoricosECF])"
                    actionListener="#{ecfController.removerHistorico}">
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton value="Não" process="@this"
                    onclick="exclusaoHistoricoEcf.hide()" />
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </p:confirmDialog>

    <p:confirmDialog id="exclusaoEcfId" appendTo="@(body)"
        message="Voce deseja realmente excluir?" header="Confirmação"
        severity="alert" widgetVar="exclusaoEcf">
        <div style="margin-left: 60px">
            <p:commandButton value="Sim" process="@this"
                oncomplete="exclusaoEcf.hide()" update="@([id$=rendererTabEcf])"
                actionListener="#{controller.removerEcf}">
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Não" process="@this"
                onclick="exclusaoEcf.hide()" />
        </div>
    </p:confirmDialog>
</ui:define>
```

As you can see all the tabs are being included, so here is the tab with the fields I want to process, the button is the one with id="botaoSalvarCadastro"..

```
<ui:composition 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 
<p:tab title="Cadastro">
    <ui:include src="/restrito/pessoa/compositeVinculoPessoa.xhtml" />

    <hr width="100%"/>
    <h:panelGroup id="dadosClienteSH" layout="block">
        <p:panelGrid id="camposCadastroClienteSH" columns="4" style="max-width:1000px; width:100%">
            <p:outputLabel value="Contador: "/>
            <h:panelGroup id="pgContador" layout="block" style="display: inline-block; float: left; ">
                <p:inputText  disabled="true"
                    value="#{contadorController.entidade.pessoa.nome_razaoSocial}" style="margin-right:20px; min-width:186px"/>
                <p:commandButton value="..." actionListener="#{contadorController.irPesquisa}" process="@this"
                    oncomplete="PF('dialogVinculoContador').show()" update=":formDialogVinculoContador"/>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:outputLabel value="Item de Categoria de Cliente: "/>
            <h:panelGroup id="pgItemCategoriaCliente" layout="block" style="display: inline-block; float: left; ">
                <p:inputText disabled="true"
                    value="#{itemCategoriaClienteController.entidade.descricao}" style="margin-right:20px; min-width:186px"/>
                <p:commandButton value="..." actionListener="#{itemCategoriaClienteController.irPesquisa}" process="@this"
                    oncomplete="PF('dialogVinculoItemCategoriaCliente').show()" update=":formDialogVinculoItemCategoriaCliente"/>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:outputLabel value="Grupo de Cliente: "/>
            <h:panelGroup id="pgItemCategoriaGrupoCliente" layout="block" style="display: inline-block; float: left; ">
                <p:inputText  disabled="true"
                    value="#{grupoClienteController.entidade.descricao}" style="margin-right:20px; min-width:186px"/>
                <p:commandButton value="..." actionListener="#{grupoClienteController.irPesquisa}" process="@this"
                    oncomplete="PF('dialogVinculoGrupoCliente').show()" update=":formDialogVinculoGrupoCliente"/>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:outputLabel value="MacAdress Servidor: "/>
            <p:inputText id="macAdress" value="#{controller.entidade.macAdressServidor}" disabled="#{controller.status == 'VISUALIZACAO'}"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Data de Travamento: "/>
            <p:calendar id="licensaLimiteTravaCadastro" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" disabled="#{controller.status == 'VISUALIZACAO'}"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obrigatório" value="#{controller.entidade.licensaLimiteTrava}"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Data Limite para Update: "/>
            <p:calendar id="licensaLimiteUpdateCadastro" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" disabled="#{controller.status == 'VISUALIZACAO'}"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obrigatório" value="#{controller.entidade.licensaLimiteUpdate}"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Data Limite da Garantia: "/>
            <p:calendar id="licensaLimiteGarantiaCadastro" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" disabled="#{controller.status == 'VISUALIZACAO'}"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obrigatório" value="#{controller.entidade.licensaLimiteGarantia}"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Data Limite do Contrato: "/>
            <p:calendar id="licensaLimiteContratoCadastro" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" disabled="#{controller.status == 'VISUALIZACAO'}"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obrigatório" value="#{controller.entidade.licensaLimiteContrato}"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Data Limite do Atraso: "/>
            <p:calendar id="licensaLimiteAtrasoCadastro" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" disabled="#{controller.status == 'VISUALIZACAO'}"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obrigatório" value="#{controller.entidade.licensaLimiteAtraso}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <p:commandButton id="botaoSalvarCadastro" actionListener="#{controller.salvar}" style="margin-top:15px"
                        value="Salvar" process="dadosClienteSH"/>   
</p:tab>
```

I have already tried to use @([id$=dadosClienteSH]), I also tried to process field by field, anyway it only reach my bean with process="@this".

I am stuck on this, hope someone can give me some light.

Comment: Maybe you've forgotten to add your code between `<h:form>...</h:form>`

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but that was not the case, anyway I solved it, I am posting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after reading many Primefaces forums posts, the problem was happening because I was trying to process a panelGroup where my button was not included so the button wasn't processing itself at all. To solve this I added both the button and the panelGroup in the process attribute of the button. There is the code:

```
<p:commandButton id="botaoSalvarCadastro" actionListener="#{controller.salvar}" style="margin-top:15px" 
        value="Salvar" update="@form" process="@this,dadosCadastro" ajax="true" rendered="#{controller.status != 'VISUALIZACAO'}"/>
```

Comment: Just to make things clear, I changed the name of the panelGroup from "dadosClienteSH" to "dadosCadastro"